# How do I make config.exceptions_app work with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, rails-routing, custom-exceptions

In my Rails 3.2 app, I'm trying to use config.exceptions_app to route exceptions through the routing table to render error-specific pages (especially one for 401 Forbidden). Here's what I've got so far for configuration:

```
# application.rb
config.action_dispatch.rescue_responses.merge!('Error::Forbidden' => :forbidden)
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ErrorsController.action(:show).call(env) }

# development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false

# test.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

And now the meat of the matter:

```
module Error
  class Forbidden < StandardError
  end
end

class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'error'

  def show
    exception       = env['action_dispatch.exception']
    status_code     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, exception).status_code
    rescue_response = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[exception.class.name]

    render :action => rescue_response, :status => status_code, :formats => [:html]
  end

  def forbidden
    render :status => :forbidden, :formats => [:html]
  end
end
```

When I want to render that 401 response, I simply `raise Error::Forbidden` which, in the development environment works perfectly. But when running an example in rspec, e.g.:

```
it 'should return http forbidden' do
  put :update, :id => 12342343343
  response.should be_forbidden
end
```

it fails miserably:

```
1) UsersController PUT update when attempting to edit another record should return http forbidden
   Failure/Error: put :update, :id => 12342343343
   Error::Forbidden:
     Error::Forbidden
```

Could someone help me understand why this doesn't work in my test environment? I *could* put a #rescue_from in ApplicationController, but if I have to do that to get my tests working, I'm not sure what the point of using `config.exceptions_app` is in the first place. :-\

**EDIT: As a workaround, I wound up putting the following at the end of config/environments/test.rb** It's hecka gross, but seems to work okay.

```
module Error
  def self.included(base)
    _not_found = -> do
      render :status => :not_found, :text => 'not found'
    end

    _forbidden = -> do
      render :status => :forbidden, :text => 'forbidden'
    end

    base.class_eval do
      rescue_from 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound', :with => _not_found
      rescue_from 'ActionController::UnknownController', :with => _not_found
      rescue_from 'AbstractController::ActionNotFound', :with => _not_found
      rescue_from 'ActionController::RoutingError', :with => _not_found
      rescue_from 'Error::Forbidden', :with => _forbidden
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In `config/environments/test.rb` set:

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I already have that line in that file and it doesn't solve my problem. If I comment out the Error module that I show above, my tests go back to failing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Be careful where you raise your exception. If it is in a `before_filter` / `before_action`, your exception will be swallowed. Move your finder code to the actual method and your exception should show up in your specs.