# Override default json format for errors in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When an error occurs in Rails API Only, the server responds with an error in json with the following format: `{"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error"}`.

The format is the same for other errors as well: `{"status":404,"error":"Not Found"}`.

I want to render the errors with the format: `{"errors": [{status: 404, title: "Not found"}]}`.

Basically I want to change the format of all errors to be the same and I don't find a way to do that.

I know I can use (for example) `rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :my_method` and override the single exceptions but this means I have to list all possible exceptions and return the appropriate code, when Rails is already doing that.

What I am looking for is a method that can be overridden, and that I can use to change the "default" error format of Rails.

Comment: Since ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound like all errors is a subclass of StandardError (Technically its a subclass of ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError which is a subclass of StandardError), can't you just rescue_from StandardError, so that you don't need to list all of the possible exceptions?

Comment: @bkimble there must be a better solution than using a catch-all.

Comment: And how do I return the correct status @bkimble? Rails defines already a status for each error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [configure an exceptions_app in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration).

The default Middleware which manages exceptions and render the errors is `ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions`.

First thing is to override this middleware to implement our custom behavior. Inside `app/middlewares/action_dispatch` folder create a `public_exceptions_plus.rb` file with the following:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class PublicExceptionsPlus < PublicExceptions
    def call(env)
      request = ActionDispatch::Request.new(env)
      status = request.path_info[1..-1].to_i
      content_type = request.formats.first
      # define here your custom format
      body = { errors: [{ status: status,
                          title: Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES.fetch(status, Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES[500]) }] }

      render(status, content_type, body)
    end
  end
end
```

after that, inside `config/application.rb` add the following:

```
 config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ActionDispatch::PublicExceptionsPlus.new(Rails.public_path).call(env) }
```

Thanks @smallbutton.com for the input. I think this is a better solution since it does not require a controller but just a middleware.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to do this in Rails is probably [defining an `exceptions_app`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) (see `config.exceptions_app)` which must be a custom rack app. This will let you render your exceptions however you choose. An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457156/how-do-i-make-config-exceptions-app-work-with-rspec).

```
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ErrorsController.action(:show).call(env) }

class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'error'

  def show
   exception       = env['action_dispatch.exception']
   status_code     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, exception).status_code

   # render whatever you want here
  end
end
```

You can also check what the [default implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/public_exceptions.rb) by rails is.

There is also a gem called `exception_handler` that might be an alternative here.
More resources: https://devblast.com/b/jutsu-12-custom-error-pages-in-rails-4